# How to make image fill the left hand side of the screen in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a custom login page in bootstrap.

On the left hand side I want my image and on the right side I want my form, I need it to be responsive so on certain screen sizes the image may well need to disappear as I don't want it to become distorted.

The problem I am having it that the image is not showing fully but is instead getting "cut off" when the form ends.

Here my html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 background_image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- LOGIN FORM HERE -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this CSS but to no avail.

```
.background_image{
  background-image: url(/static/picture.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: flex;
}
```

Here is an image to try and explain better:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGywP.png)

How can I get it so that the entire left hand screen is filled up with my image?

Comment: the background-image won't take up space in the DOM like content (i.e. an `<img>`) would.

Comment: just put `max-width: 100%;` on the img to make it responsive

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the height of the container. Not sure if it's nested in another container but either way maybe try:

```
<div class="container-fluid mh-100">
```

if you want/need it to be full height and using Bootstrap 4, if not another approach with CSS would be:

```
.container-fluid {
  height:100vh;
}
```

Or set the height of the DIV with the image to whatever you need it to be

```
.background_image{
  ...
  height:200px;
}
```

Comment: mh-100 didn't do anything, height does ut it won't be responsive then?

Comment: Did you try adding `height:100vh;` to .background_image? It would be responsive with that because it's not set to a specific height.